# Eliminating Duplicate Data from MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is a part of MySQL query in CodeIgniter and when I am echoing the **sub_product** it duplicates the same product name.Is there anything I can do to eliminating duplicate data other than using **$this->db->order_by();**.

Thanks!!!
Ann

```
   $this->db->select(array(            
            'GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_sub_products.sub_product_name SEPARATOR "<th>" ) as sub_product'
        ));
```

Comment: I'm not a CodeIgniter user but I believe that GROUP BY col_name would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `group_by():`

```
$this->db->select(array(            
            'GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_sub_products.sub_product_name SEPARATOR "<th>") as sub_product'
))->group_by("sub_product_name");
```

I'm not entirely sure on the name of the product name column, so you will have to change that.